# Send data by ENC28J60 in stm32

Tags: ethernet, stm32, spi

I have a development board of stm32f103VE and i want to use enc28j60 to send data to PC .
I have a sample code from st.com .I used it but there wasn't any response and when i joint the cable from my board to PC ,the orange and green LED weren't on. I am not very familiar with this protocol to transmit data. 
Can anybody help me to dissolve this problem?
Should i configure something in my PC?

Answer (score 0):

Two ethernet devices would communicate if they are in the same subnet. so the subnet mask of the pc and what you set in your microcontroller must be same. 
If you are directly connecting to PC (without any switch), use a cross ethernet cable